# copying specific elements from array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array like `[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]` and I'm looking for a way to take the `[1,4,5]` position elements from the array to a new array for example. So in this case the new array would be `[11,14,15]`

is there a neat way of doing this without running through a loop?

Comment: `idx = [1,4,5]; np.array(arr)[idx]`

Answer (score 0):

```
new_arr = numpy.array([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])[[1,4,5]]
```